# How to get rid of the unwanted extra space in the text height of HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, safari, space

**Problem:**

It is best described when using a H2-element. When the height of this element is key to your design you will come across a huge problem. The height is different on multiple devices and thus can really mess up your design.

This is shown in the image below. The black space next to the question mark shows the unwanted "extra space" that appeared on mobile safari.

[image]

**Try it yourself**

I found a way that you can test it for yourself. Just open this link on different devices and you will see that the real height is different with the exact same code snippet.

http://jsfiddle.net/RwPk7/40/

**Research**

```
 - MAC Chrome  : 18px 
 - MAC Safari  : 18px
 - MAC Firefox : 17px
 - iPad        : 20px
 - iPhone      : 20px
 - Android     : 19px
 - WIN Chrome  : 18px
 - WIN IE      : 18px
```

**Possible Answer**

```
font-size: 13px; 
line-height: 1.231; // Borrowed from HTML5 Boilerplate
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RwPk7/45/

Comment: some discussion of this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283383/align-headings-to-same-baseline-regardless-following-text

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be an issue of how bold text is implemented in Mobile Safari.  This appears to work in both browsers without bold text:
http://jsfiddle.net/RwPk7/23/

The bold text is rendered at different heights for each though, and that combined with the fact that browsers center text vertically to line height by default makes a simple universal solution difficult.

So this should be ok if you can live without the bold text.

Comment: Have you tested this on iPad/iPhone cause the bug does still occure. I did have a break through thou.

Comment: I did test on an iPhone.  Don't have an iPad handy.  What are you seeing on the iPhone?